# creating a folder one level above the present location

Tags: bash, shell

I need to create a simple shell script to create a folder one level above the present location of the script. I was successful in getting the present location with:

```
#!/bin/sh
pwd
```

However, I got stuck how to go one level up to create a folder, suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `..` in your path to go up a directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir ./../foldername
```

Answer (score 4):

Just type :

```
cd ..
```

to move up one level , then `mkdir` your dir.

Or :

```
mkdir ../dir
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the path variable and create folder like this

- WorkspacePath -> C:\sample\workspace
- result -> C:\sample

> workspaceDirName="workspace"
>
> DIR="$(dirname "${WorkspacePath}")" ; FILE="$(basename "${workspaceDirName}")
>
> #print file path
>
> echo ${DIR}
>
> #creating folder
>
> mkdir ${DIR}/foldername`